# What's the proper way to inject/escape a string variable into a string

Tags: c++, mysql

Here is my pseudo-code for cpp

```
#include <string>    
int createuser(string user)
{
   sqlquery("insert into users(user) values('user')");
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can the contents of the string change when your program runs to choose different variables or expressions? If yes, you may want to reword your question to be clearer. If no, the answer is simply `"insert into users(" + user + ") values ('" + user + "')"`

Comment: it worked perfectly thank you!

Comment: @Tristan you must **never** build queries this way. It is extremely dangerous.  Look up "SQL injection" vulnerabilities.